# Vue.js – Unit Testing multi file components

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

As mentioned in the title, I am using multi file components with Vue.js i.e. I've got a separate html, javascript and scss file. Thus my vue file looks like this:

```
<template src="./my-component.html"></template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

The vue Unit Testing guide

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html

only covers single file components.

Most likely I need to invoke webpack to build a single file component in order to be able to test it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try just to import the component.vue file just like the guide you mention? I am pretty sure that if you do that all the necessary files are loaded to the test. You don't need a bundler, importing your `.vue` I assume will fetch all the requirements.

Comment: did you find the solution to this?